# htaccess rewrite root url to subfolder with accessing other folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have following folder structure in apache server.

```
Public_html
-->admin
    --->admin_login.php
-->website
    --->index.php
```

since the index.php inside the website folder,
i have given following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/$1 [L,NC]
```

so that the when the user enter root url , it will appear "www.myurl.com" instead of "www.myurl.com/website/"

but the issue is, i could not be able to access admin_login.php.

is there anyway to modify .htaccess,  to come website/index.php in main url and able to access admin_login.php(both)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code(not my downvote btw), kindly do mention details like : **from** which url **to** which url you want to redirect/rewrite, that will help us understanding your question in better manner, cheers.

Comment: Hi, My index file is in myurl.com/website/index.php. when user type myurl.com, it should display myurl.com/website/index.php without changing url. but i could able to access myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php as well.

Comment: basically i want to keep website in separate folder and call index file when user type main url. i want to access admin url as well. is this proper approach? please do share your comment

Comment: I get that but if you could let us know like: **from** which url **to** which url you want to redirect/rewrite, that will help us understanding your question in better manner, cheers.

Comment: currently the website works www.myurl.com/website/index.php ,www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php. without any redirect.... what i require is www.myurl.com/index.php (this should bring content inside of website folder), www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php

Comment: You mean `www.myurl.com/index.php` should show contents of `www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php`?

Comment: I mean ```www.myurl.com/index.php``` should show contents of ```www.myurl.com/website/index.php``` and ```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php``` should work as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an exception to existing rule like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(website|admin)/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* website/$0 [L]
```

Negative condition `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/(website|admin)/` will match every URI except URIs that start with `/website/` or `/admin/`. This will allow you to directly open `www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php`.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ website/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: HI Ravinder, case1. ```www.myurl.com/index.php``` should redirect to ```www.myurl.com/website/index.php```(without changing url).  case2. ```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php``` should redirect to ```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php```.

Comment: i tried ```RedirectMatch ^/$ /website/ ``` it redirected from ```www.myurl.com/index.php``` to ```www.myurl.com/website/index.php``` (but url also changed). and  it redirected  from```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php``` to ```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php```.   i want to keep the url unchanged in case1 that is ```www.myurl.com/index.php```.

Comment: @JohnsonEmmanuel, For `www.myurl.com/index.php should redirect to www.myurl.com/website/index.php(without changing url)` yes this should work with given rules. For your 2nd condition `case2. www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php should redirect to www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php` both the URLs are looking same whats the change in it?

Comment: when  ``` www.myurl.com/index.php``` redirects to ```www.myurl.com/website/index.php```(without changing url), it blocks 'admin' folder. i.e.admin could not be able login with this path ```www.myurl.com/admin/admin_login.php```

Comment: @JohnsonEmmanuel, Ok, could you please try my edited code once and let me know how it goes?